# Django testing: test fails on create view with post request

Tags: django, testing, django-views

**I am building test for my views and I am unable to build correct one for generic CreateView.
I am following this documentation mostly:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/pl/4.0/topics/testing/advanced/#django.test.RequestFactory
Does anyone have sollution for this?**

blog.models

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    intro = models.TextField()
    content = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

blog.views

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'intro', 'content', 'category']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

blog.urls

```
app_name = 'blog'
urlpatterns = [
    path('post/new/', views.PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    # some other paths,]
```

blog.tests.test_views

```
class PostViewsTests(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):

        self.author = User.objects.create_user(
            username='abcUser, 
            email='abcuser@mail.com',             
            password='abcpassword')
        self.category = Category.objects.create(name='New test category')
        self.new_post = Post.objects.create(
            title='Lorem Ipsum',
            intro='Neque porro quisquam est ',
            content='There is no one who loves pain itself...',
            author=self.author,
            category=self.category)

        self.client = Client()
        self.factory = RequestFactory()

def test_post_create_view_if_adds_new_post(self):
    data = {
        'title': 'Lorem Ipsum2',
        'intro': 'Neque porro quisquam...',
        'content': 'Neque porro quisquam... - There is no...',
        'category': self.category
    }
    request = self.factory.post(reverse('blog:post-create'), data=data)
    request.user = self.author
    response = views.PostCreateView.as_view()(request)

    newest_post = Post.objects.order_by('-date').first()

    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    self.assertEqual(newest_post.title, 'Lorem Ipsum2')
```

test's result:

```
Found 6 test(s).
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
.F....
======================================================================
FAIL: test_post_create_view_if_adds_new_post (blog.tests.test_views.PostViewsTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\twiad\PycharmProjects\nothing_inclusive\blog\tests\test_views.py",         
line 129, in test_post_create_view_if_adds_new_post
    self.assertEqual(newest_post.title, 'Lorem Ipsum2')
AssertionError: 'Lorem Ipsum' != 'Lorem Ipsum2'
- Lorem Ipsum
+ Lorem Ipsum2
?            +


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 6 tests in 1.084s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Comment: you probably resolved by the time but you pass 'Lorem Ipsum2' in data and test assertEqual with 'Lorem Ipsum' that correspond to the object totle created... just change 'Lorem Ipsum2' to 'Lorem Ipsum' in test_post_create_view_if_adds_new_post